# For loop always uses the last value JavaScript - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop

as the title describes the problem, I'm using a for loop to extract elements of an array and asign it to a JSON value, it´s something like this:

> hotel={ rooms: 2, price: [ 100, 200 ],  occupation: [ '1 child', '1 adult' ]

and want to push into an array of JSON

> hotels = [ { rooms:1, price: 100, occupation: '1 child' },... ]

so i tried this:

```
var json = { rooms : 1, price:null, occupation:null }    
for (let i=0 ; i < hotel.rooms ; i++){
    json.price = hotel.price[i]
    json.occupation = hotel.occupation[i]
    this.hotels.push(json)
}
```

but always the array hotels has the last values of the loop  and (shows repeated the last value of the iteration), tried using the try {throw i}  catch(ii) {...} but doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each element of the array `this.hotels` is a reference to the same `json` object - so when it is mutated, anywhere, all those array elements "see" the change. Since you mutate `json` in each loop iteration, and simply overwrite the same keys, it's inevitable that each element ends up the same.

To fix it, simply push a new "copy" of the object - which will not therefore be affected by mutations of the "master" `json` object. There are several ways to do this, one being object spread notation:

```
this.hotels.push({...json});
```

You could also use `Object.assign({}, json)` instead of the spread notation. Or keep your code as it was, but move the `var json = {...}` inside the loop while replacing `var` with `let` - to ensure it's a new local variable each time, rather than one global that's continually mutated. Lots of solutions, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

Object are reference types, you need to create a new object each time you push to the hotels array.

There are several ways to fix this **two simple ways** would be to:

Use object literals in the push method `this.hotel.push({ rooms: 1, price: hotel.price[i], occupation: hotel.occupation[i]})`

--OR--

Move the variable declaration into your loop `var json = { rooms : 1, price:null, occupation:null }`

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, just moving that line inside the loop won't fix this, unless the `var` is replaced by `let`. Only that way will the variable be scoped to the loop body, with `var` it will still be global.

Comment: Thanks, both of you gave me the solution, I changed the var for let and moved json  inside the loop and works fine.